# Kotlin Android Studio/IntelliJ "Can be joined with assignment" Inspection Warning

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm new to Koltin and really loving it so far, but I've hit a snag. I'm sure I'm missing something extremely, extremely basic here, but nonetheless, I'm a loss, and I appreciate any help.

I converted a simple java class to Kotlin using the Android Studio/IntelliJ command. After this conversion, I am getting an inspection warning that I'm unsure how to resolve. I had converted 15-20 classes (many of which were far more complicated) to Kotlin before this class, and have yet to see this warning.

[image]

Again, I know this must be something really basic. But I poured through the Kotlin docs on variables and classes and couldn't find anything related to 'assignment' or initializing multiple variables at once. Maybe I'm not understanding the terms in the message? I've also Googled the exact message string (`"Can be joined with assignment"`) to no avail.

**ImagePagerAdapter.kt**

```
abstract class ImagePagerAdapter(protected var context: Context) : PagerAdapter() {
    protected var inflater: LayoutInflater
    protected var images: List<Uri>

    interface ImageLoadingListener {
        fun onLoadingComplete()
        fun onLoadingStarted()
    }

    init {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        this.images = emptyList()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object`
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }

    fun bindImages(images: List<Uri>) {
        this.images = images
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's telling you that instead of having a separate `init` block, you could be initializing the variables at the place where you've declared them in the class, like so:

```
protected var inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
protected var images: List<Uri> = emptyList()
```

You should be getting the `Alt+Enter` intention action at the place of the warning to do this rewriting for you, like this:

[image: Join declaration and assignment intention action]

Additionally, in this form, you could clean the types up a bit like this:

```
protected var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
protected var images = emptyList<Uri>()
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense. Strangely, I didn't see the "Join declaration and assignment" intention action until I hit `Alt+Enter` to manually pull up the actions menu. Maybe that's a bug? Anyways, so glad this is resolved. Thank you for the feedback on how to clean up the type declarations as well. Learning quickly :)

Comment: But be careful, the logic changes then a bit. Init block will be called BEFORE the properties are initialized. If you assigned the properties in init block and used them directly afterwards (in the init block), then it wont work after the "optimization" by joining because they will be initialized after the init block has finished.

Comment: Property initializers and initializer blocks are ran top to bottom within the class, interleaved. See the docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors